# ImageMagickなどのライブラリを使用せず、PHPでPDFからPNGへの変換を行う方法

Tags: php

PHPでPDFlib、もしくはGDなどデフォルトのPHPモジュールを使用してPDFからPNGへの変換を行うことは可能でしょうか。
ImageMagickなど、変換用のライブラリがあるとは思うのですが、そのような外部のライブラリをインポートせず、です。

Answer (score 1):

残念ながらPHP の標準モジュールでは PDF から PNG へ変換を行う機能はありません。

ちなみに、仰られている PDFlib や GD は PHP の標準モジュールではありませんが、何らかの理由でたまたま使える状態なのだと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

PHP だけで完結するライブラリは良く知りませんが、 Ghostscript のラッパーライブラリがあるようです。

- Ghostscript-PHP
  https://github.com/alchemy-fr/Ghostscript-PHP

上のページのドキュメントにもありますが、↓のような感じでできるみたいです。

```
$transcoder = Ghostscript\Transcoder::create(array(
    'timeout' => 42,
    'gs.binaries' => '/opt/local/gs/bin/gs',
), $logger);
$transcoder->toImage('document.pdf', 'output.jpg');
```

`'gs.binaries' => '/opt/local/gs/bin/gs'` でお気づきのとおりかと思いますが、
gs がインストールされている必要はあります。

Answer (score 1):

PDFlibには、PDFのページを画像にする機能はありません。
http://pdflib.jp/product/

PDFファイルに画像を貼り付ける機能はありますが、PDFを画像にする（実質的にビュワーの機能となる）にはFoxItが有名です。（ただし、PHPは使えません）